# How should I describe the data usage of websites like Netflix or YouTube?

Tags: phrases, synonyms

I'm writing a paper on net neutrality and weighing a couple different options, but I can't make up my mind. My goal is to describe websites which, by their nature, consume a large amount of data or bandwidth. Which would fit better in an academic setting?

- Throttling speeds would make *high-bandwidth* websites such as video streaming services impossible to use.
- Throttling speeds would make *high-data* websites such as video streaming services impossible to use.
- Throttling speeds would make *bandwidth-heavy* websites such as video streaming services impossible to use.
- Throttling speeds would make *data-heavy* websites such as video streaming services impossible to use.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you talking with sites which have an inherently high data rate, or sites which are heavily accessed (or some combination)?

Comment: I’ve edited my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'High usage' would incorporate both elements, of high bandwidth and high data throughput, and also further emphasises that throttling affects the *user* of the site and not just the technical specification of the equipment running the site.

> Throttling speeds would make high usage websites, such as video streaming services, impossible to access.

Comment: Thanks! Should I hyphenate?

Comment: It is not necessary, sir, but feel free if you like it.